# Java 8 - filter empty string from List not working

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to remove an empty String from the List of Strings.

Here is what I tried, using the stream API:

```
list.stream().filter(item-> item.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

After that empty string is still present in the list. What am I missing?

Comment: isn't it `String::isEmpty`?

Comment: are you assigning the returned value to some variable?

Comment: Don't you want to keep the items which are *not* empty? You are retaining only the empty ones.

Comment: both are valid...item.isEmpty() and  String::isEmpty

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`filter()` **keeps** the elements that match the predicate. Soyou need the inverse predicate:

```
list.stream().filter(item-> !item.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will also not modify the original list. It will create a filtered copy of the original list. So you need

```
list = list.stream().filter(item-> !item.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to modify the original list, you should use

```
list.removeIf(item -> item.isEmpty());
```

or simply

```
list.removeIf(String::isEmpty);
```

Comment: I missed the ! in the question. My issue was that I was not keeping the result. I though that filter() modifies the original List.

Comment: stream() or removeIf() would not work on Array , you will have to convert the array into ArrayList like so `ArrayList<String> newArray = new ArrayList<String>(oldArray.asList());`

Comment: @ShrikantPrabhu `Arrays.stream(oldArray)` should work as well.

Comment: Had difficulties getting last two to work with `removeIf`. Second did the trick for me though. On Java 8 (1.8.0_231)

Answer (score 12):

Since java 11 there is a new method [Predicate::not](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)).

So you can write it like that:

```java
list.stream().filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you are not keeping the result. The result is returned, the original list is not altered as this is functional programming style.

```
list = list.stream().filter(item-> !item.trim().isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the string contains whitespaces? Replace `item -> item.isEmpty()` with `item -> !item.trim().isEmpty()`

Answer (score 1):

you are collecting the empty elements :)

you want the not empty so invert the predicate

```
List<String> xxx = list.stream().filter(item -> !item.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

additionally, the stream is not modifying the original list, so `Collect(Collectrors.toList())` is returning the result of the predicate :)

Comment: He is collecting empty elements and then forgetting about them :)

Comment: tnxs @TheLostMind

Answer (score 0):

You are removing non-empty strings (check your filter condition). Try:

```
list.stream().filter(item -> !item.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Otherwise, you may need to check that you're removing blanks as well:

```
list.stream().filter(item -> !item.trim().isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not removing empty Strings from the list, you were retrieving them. Your filter condition is wrong.

Try like this:

```
List<String> collect = list.stream().filter(item -> !item.trim().isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow below example, it may help you

```
String[] firstArray = {"test1", "", "test2", "test4", "", null};

    firstArray = Arrays.stream(firstArray).filter(s -> (s != null && s.length() > 0)).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
        //Java8 new api
        strings.removeIf(StringUtils::isBlank);
        //stream        strings=strings.stream().filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be your List contains null. So first filter with null check
then again filter on empty

```
    list.stream().filter(item -> null != item).filter(item -> !item.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you have apache commons lang lib use Apache StringUtils isNotBlank

```
list.stream().filter(item -> StrinUtils.isNotBlank(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```